# How do I insert a large amount of data set into the database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dataset which has 2000+ records. Is there any way that I can easily insert them into my database?

The data is currently in an excel file. It's better if anyone can suggest me an option to read the excel file and insert them into the database.

Comment: What it means - easily? Run `insert` query, that should be enough.

Comment: I meant like a simple program like thing

Answer (score 1):

save excel file to file.csv file and then import to mysql.

LOAD DATA INFILE "file.csv" INTO TABLE table_name

Answer (score 0):

Export as CSV file from Excel, then import it in MySQL. It does support CSV file imports.

---

Actually 1000 records is not a large amount. That would only be 2-3 `INSERT` queries depending on the number of columns.

Use this syntax if you want to use queries:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, ...) VALUES (<values of the first row), (<values of the second row), ...
```

Build up query with about 300 rows then send it.